# Dropzone js with angular 4

Tags: angular, dropzone.js

Is anyone used dropzone Js library with angular 2 or 4 before ?
and if there is some useful examples or links
thanks

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-dropzone-wrapper
check this\

Answer (score 8):

There is an Angular 5+ wrapper for Dropzone that can be found [here](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-dropzone-wrapper).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's a bit late, after some research I found these info to make work dropzone 5.0.2 with Angular 5:

- put dropzone.js library under `src/js/` (create the `js` dir, if not already created)
- add `js/dropzone.js` in the list of scripts in `.angular-cli.json`
- As described [here](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-angular-2-apps-ff274ba601af), run the following command in cmd/shell, at the root of your angular project (where `.angular-cli.json` is located):

  ```
  npm install --save @types/dropzone
  ```
- Now you are able to import dropzone in your typescript classes like this:

  ```
  import * as dropzone from 'dropzone';
  ```

You may also integrate it as an Angular component (Angular 2+) like described it [this article](https://sharpten.com/blog/2016/08/06/using-dropzone-js-angular-2.html).

**WARNING**: I didn't test it, thus, maybe, something is missing or wrong. I finally used another library.

Comment: which library do you used ? thnks !

Comment: I use ng2-file-upload (https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload)

Comment: You can see an example of usage here: https://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/

Answer (score 0):

If you're not bound to `dropzone.js` since it's not optimized for use with Angular I might suggest the following library to you.

I've written a highly customizable Angular component which implements Drag'n'Drop behavior. It returns a list of the dropped files as an output event.
This can be found [here](https://github.com/peterfreeman/ngx-dropzone).

After you imported the module you have access to the component:

```
<ngx-dropzone [multiple]="false" [maxFileSize]="2000"></ngx-dropzone>
```

You have some options to set and it comes with a decent default styling (screenshots can be found in the GitHub repo). If you want to, you can even take your own `div` container with your custom styles and hover effects and put it in the dropzone. Details on this can be found in the API description.

```
<ngx-dropzone [customContent]="customDropzone" (filesDropped)="onFilesDropped($event)">
<ng-template #customDropzone>
    <div class="custom-dropzone">
        This is my custom content
    </div>
</ng-template>
```